# Receiving NaN as an output when using the pow() function to generate a Decimal

Tags: swift, swift3

I've been at this for hours so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.

I'm using the `pow(_ x: Decimal, _ y: Int) -> Decimal` function to help generate a monthly payment amount using a basic formula. I have this function linked to the `infix operator` `***` but I've tried using it just by typing out the function and have the same problem.

Xcode was yelling at me yesterday for having too long of a formula, so I broke it up into a couple constants and incorporated that into the overall formula I need.

Code:

```
precedencegroup PowerPrecedence { higherThan: MultiplicationPrecedence }
infix operator *** : PowerPrecedence
func *** (radix: Decimal, power: Int) -> Decimal {
    return (pow((radix), (power)))
}

func calculateMonthlyPayment() {
        let rateAndMonths: Decimal = ((0.0199 / 12.0) + (0.0199 / 12.0))
        let rateTwo: Decimal = ((1.0+(0.0199 / 12.0)))
        loan12YearsPayment[0] = ((rateAndMonths / rateTwo) *** 144 - 1.0) * ((values.installedSystemCost + loanFees12YearsCombined[0]) * 0.7)
```

When I print to console or run this in the simulator, the output is `NaN`. I know the `pow` function itself is working properly because I've tried it with random integers.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your maths. `(rateAndMonths / rateTwo)` is 0.00331117563374071416759264060060795376 Is that correct?

Comment: I second what Sweeper said. Each time your multiply `rateAndMonths / rateTwo` it becomes a smaller number. Doing that for 144 times is giving a NaN.

Comment: I've been looking at the formula for so long I'm not even sure, but I get what you guys are saying. The formula I'm trying to use is `( r + r / ( (1+r) ^ months -1) ) * principal loan amount` where `r` is the decimal for the interest rate / 12. In this case, `r` = `.0199 / 12`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly find my point of view for this Apple function implementation, Note the following examples:

> ```
> pow(1 as Decimal, -2) // 1; (1 ^ Any number) = 1 
> pow(10 as Decimal, -2) // NAN 
> pow(0.1 as Decimal, -2) // 100 
> pow(0.01 as Decimal, -2) // 10000 
> pow(1.5 as Decimal, -2) // NAN 
> pow(0.5 as Decimal, -2) // NAN
> ```

It seems like, pow with decimal don't consider any floating numbers except for 10 basis. So It deals with:

> 0.1 ^ -2 == (1/10) ^ -2 == 10 ^ 2 // It calculates it appropriately, It's 10 basis 10, 100, 1000, ...
>
> 1.5 ^ -2 == (3/2) ^ -2 // (3/2) is a floating number ,so deal with it as Double not decimal, It returns NAN.
>
> 0.5 ^ -2 == (1/2) ^ -2 // (2) isn't 10 basis, So It will be dealt as (1/2) as It is, It's a floating number also. It returns NAN.